What does tune mean here?
https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/4564443-senate-rankings-seats-flip/ says

For some national Democrats, Moreno, who was endorsed by Trump, is the perfect candidate for Brown to take on this fall — the Senate Majority PAC believed it to the tune of a $2.7 million ad campaign to boost Moreno ahead of the primary.

What does tune mean here? How is it used here?

'To the tune of...' is an idiomatic way of emphasising that the amount or extent of something (such as money) is considerable.  My son crashed my car. I am out of pocket to the tune of $1000. The Senate Majority PAC believed Moreno was a good candidate, so much so that they allowed an ad campaign costing 2.7 million dollars.

I hope that what the PAC did won't backfire

Moreno seems to have a weird grasp of history (and truth) saying his family left Colombia in 1971 to flee 'socialism', when in fact the government there was the National Front government. The first leftwing government in Colombia in modern times did not start until 2022. Still, he is appealing to a demographic where brain power is not very great.

You need to look up stuff before posting. Just a thought.//Gees, that Moreno, another creature feature. Now there's an idiom! :)

This is an idiom "To the tune of".  meaning "to (about) the stated amount". Typically it is used with a sum of money, and emphasises the amount of money as "lots".

Joe supported Laura's marathon run to the tune of $500.

Your example just means that the Senate majority PAC spent about $2.7 million on an ad campaign for Moreno.
